# Retrieving NSURL from NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have Stored path `NSURL` as `NSString` to `NSUserDefault` while retrieving `NSUrl` from `NSUserDefault`, I am getting `NSURL` path like `"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EB2E7DCD-5B73-4B0B-9BC5-6758AF75C68C/Documents/FinalVideo-958.mov"` but Video is displaying from this link....the above path is from iphone device

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is issue? The url show the local video file path of your device..

Comment: I am getting the path of that video ..but the video is not displaying

Comment: did you convert back NSString to NSURL ?

Comment: Does the file still exist? What's your code to get the URL from the user defaults and to play it? Have you checked whether the player is actually passed the correct path?

Comment: Please edit your question and put your code which you are trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use relative path same like below code.

```
NSArray *paths =   NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FinalVideo-958.mov"];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPathDocs])
{
   NSLog(@"video file found.");
}
```

Comment: Why would the path change?

Comment: If whole path will be saved then after restart the App path of App folder means "var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EB2E7DCD-5B73-4B0B-9BC5-6758AF75C68C" may change thats why

Comment: No, that path will not change. Why should it? The app's bundle will not move. If the path was valid, it will remain valid.

Comment: The path does change: According to [Technical Note TN2406](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html) *Beginning in iOS 8, the Documents and Library directories are no longer siblings of your application's bundle.*

Comment: @PayalManiyar Thank u it works fine now... sorry i cannot upvote since it requires 15 reputation..

Comment: No problem.It's okay.